# Grails execute service method after bootstrap completes

Tags: grails, bootstrapping, servletcontextlistener

Just a quick one to see whether it is possible to run a block of code after the bootstrap's init() has completed?

Hows the best way to go about it?

I have some external systems I need to connect to, and I want to show an 'index' page saying 'Connecting to sub systems' or something similar whilst this block completes, and then once its done the application works as normal.

Am I right in thinking you cant access a page until after bootstrap? Is there a simple way to restrict people accessing other parts of the system whilst this service runs? Does this seem feasible?

Cheers for any help!

Comment: Do you need to have a screen for it? You can call your service in bootstrap and if you care about the result, create a domain to store connections succeed or failed and create a page to show the result. Until bootstrap is done you cannot see your screens. If you need this to happen on the page, then I can suggest another approach.

Comment: Yes, although i disagree, the on highs want a screen showing a little information as it goes through this part of the setting up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement as you also pointed out bootstrap is not your friend. you need a view and controller for your screen and a service for your connection logic to external systems.  You also need a flag or a method for sanity check of the communication within the scope of application or session. Then I would suggest to create a filter and check if you have the connections, if not redirect them to the controller that will connect it. 
Sudo:

```
class ConnectionFilters {
def filters = {
    loginCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
        before = {
            if (!session.connection ) {
                redirect(controller:'connection',action: 'connect')
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class controller {
    def connectionService
    def connect (){
        try {
            connectionService.connectTo('systemx')
            connectionService.connectTo('systemy')
            connectionService.connectTo('systemz')
        }
        catch(e){
            session.connection = false
            redirect view:'error'
        }
        session.connection = true
    }
}


class ConnectionService {
    def connectTo(systemname){
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing i need. I didn't even think of a filter. Cheers for that, good answer and a great starting point.